Can we publicly access to CryptoSE visitor analytics?
I think due to Corona pandemic or any other known reasons recently CryptoSE is slowing down.
Can we have some analytics about the number of visitors or some service like Goole Analytics?
Maybe there could be some idea to boost it again.

Access to site analytics is a 25k reputation privilege. I'll probably post an answer tomorrow. Until then, have a look at the chat logs from a month ago which should still be accurate.

@SEJPM I am still waiting for your answer.

Oh, I didn't bother because Glorfindel essentially answered it as far as I can tell.

Users with 25k+ reputation have access to site analytics which includes traffic information. The Help Center says:

Since this is a restricted privilege, we'd prefer you not share the raw data. However, we do hope you will share your analysis of the data with other users on meta.

but I see graphs of the site analytics now and then on other sites as well, so perhaps someone can verify your hypothesis.
Mere mortals like you and me can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer; this query lists the number of questions per day (with a 7 day moving average, to account for the weekends being calmer):

The number of questions went up from March (when the pandemic really started outside China) but is now back to the level it was at the beginning of the year. Looking at longer terms, I don't see a fluctuation that is out of the ordinary.
The average number of answers shows a similar pattern.

Thanks for jumping in Glorfindel (although "mere mortals" usually don't have a > 100K on Meta) :)

A nice companion query would be the number of answers.

@kelalaka here you go - not much difference, I guess.

I think that we are a bit down from ~12 Q's a day to ~10 Q's a day in June, but actually the spike of Q's in May was higher.
